# Strange way of concatenating values in Java

Tags: java

```
System.out.println("" + 1+1);
System.out.println(1+1 + "");
```

Why is the first line printing `11` and the second line printing `2`?

Comment: Priority order, from left to right.

Comment: (1+1) will give 2 in both cases

Answer (score 4):

The expression is evaluated from left to right.

In the first expression, ""+1+1 is evaluated as concatenation of a String and two integers.

In the second expression, the first + is between two ints, so it is treated as addition, and the result of that addition is concatenated with an empty String. BTW, `System.out.println (1+1);` would print the same output as `System.out.println (1+1+"");`

Answer (score 1):

If you understand these rules the answer is easy to understand.

- The evaluation is from left to right when using multiple +
- When + is used with and Integer and a String the result becomes a String
- When + is used with two Integers the result is an Integer.

The following

```
System.out.println("" + 1 + 1);
```

is understood by the compiler as

```
System.out.println(("" + 1) + 1); // "" + 1 becomes "1" (String)
System.out.println("1" + 1);      // "1" + 1 becomes "11" (String)
```

Whereas

```
System.out.println(1 + 1 + "");
```

is understood by the compiler as

```
System.out.println((1 + 1) + ""); // 1 + 1 becomes 2 (Integer)
System.out.println((2) + "");     // 2 + "" becomes "2" (String)
```

Some programmers use "" + as a shortcut for making the result a String. For example foo takes a String, but x is an int.

```
foo("" + x)
```

this can be more clearly written

```
foo(String.valueOf(x))
```

or

```
foo(Integer.toString(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("" + 1+1);
```

The first element of that expression is a `String`, therefore the JVM uses the overloaded version of `+` which concatenates values together instead of adding them.

```
System.out.println(1+1 + "");
```

The first elements of this expression are primitive types. Therefore the "original" behavior of the `+` operater will be used. It builds a sum of the primitves. The next `+` finds a `String` as part of the expression. Therefore it uses the overloaded "version" again and concatenates the values.

Also the order of evaluation is responsible for the result.

For example, this prints `2` as well:

```
System.out.println("" + (1 + 1));
```

because the expression in the parenthesis are evaluated first.